# Extract address from google maps geocode api result

Tags: regex

Can anyone show me how to match the actual address string from this line?

```
"formatted_address" : "33 Johns Street, Canterbury NSW 2111, Australia",
```

Basically everything between `"formatted_address" : "` and `",`

I'm trying to set up a tasker action which extracts the address returned by google. Tasker supports Java regular expression only.

Comment: Trying to parse JSON?

Comment: devnull, after looking up on JSON, I've got everything working. really thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Here is the task that displays a rough current address in dashclock. Just swap out the very last action for wherever you want to use the address. [Tasker-task: current address](https://www.dropbox.com/s/15fsvwhecb83utz/Current_Address.tsk.xml)

Answer (score 1):

This regex will return the address string into capturing group 1.

```
"formatted_address"[^"]+"([^"]+)
```

You may or may not need to modify it to be compatible with your program

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure because I am a beginnner in regex, just try this

```
/(^\d+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+),\s([a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s\d+),\s([a-zA-Z]+)/
```